# Find records with a time field in the last 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

In my SQL query how do i find records in the last 24 hours? 
I am using time() function for inserting into db.
I am using time-stamp the time is stored in this format.Eg 1332673046

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Records inserted by hour, for the last 24 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783740/mysql-records-inserted-by-hour-for-the-last-24-hours)

Comment: Does the record contain any timestamp/datetime column?

Comment: @Shiplu yes i am using timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select somefield from yourtable where timefield >= subtime(current_timestamp(), '1 00:00:00');
```

Comment: not working when i run in mysql it says 'MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)'.

Comment: zero rows is not an error. It just means, that there are no rows matching the condition. This happens, if all rows are older than 24 hours, or if the table is empty.

Comment: but the problem is that I have rows entered 30 minutes before?

Comment: I found the error. Do not use curtime(). Use current_timestamp() instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BETWEEN`

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE created_at  BETWEEN '2012-03-31 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2012-03-31 23:59:59 UTC'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain if you are looking to check within the same calendar day, or as you say within the past 24 hours, so here's what I usually do for both cases:

a) For the same calendar day:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), myTable.myDate, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
```

b) For the date to be within the past 24 hours (inclusive)

```
DATEDIFF(hour, myTable.myDate, GETDATE()) <= 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple DATE arithmetic would do,

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `table1` 
WHERE  `time_col` BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW()- INTERVAL 24 HOURS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are storing dates as unix timestamps then you need [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) like this

```
SELECT
  // fields you need
FROM `table`
WHERE
  `date_field` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE_SUB(NOW() INTERVAL 24 HOUR) ) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

You might want to consider storing dates in MySQLs [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) format as it makes date calculations in MySQL much easier.